# What in the world does this mean (C++ function pointer)?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

So I was looking at some c++ source code and wanted to know just what the heck this meant. I think it means call tmp as a function but I'm not sure.

```
char* tmp;
///stuff filling tmp with values
((void (*)())tmp)();
```

Comment: Casting a `char*` to a function pointer and attempting to call it... What good can come out of that?

Comment: It casts `tmp` to a pointer to a function with signature `void()`, then invokes that function. @chris : It's not uncommon to generate machine code on the fly and execute it, but this particular approach won't work on most modern OSs due to [DEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention).

Comment: Oh it's casting it... makes sense now.

Comment: @ildjarn: That depends on how the memory for `tmp` is allocated.  If it's allocated in executable memory using `VirtualAlloc`+`VirtualProtect` on Windows or `mmap` with `PROT_EXEC` on POSIX systems, it's a perfectly fine way of generating and executing machine code on the fly.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield : Right, but no allocation is shown here, so I assumed `new[]`/`malloc`. :-]

Comment: Yea VirtualAlloc was used. This makes sense now cause the source was for a game mod so I'm sure there were many hacky tricks used.

Comment: BTW, the [cdecl](http://cdecl.org) program is very helpful.  It can't quite handle the full expression, but it can tell you that the subexpression [`(void (*)())tmp`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=%28void+%28*%29%28%29%29tmp) is casting `tmp` to a "pointer to function returning void".

Comment: @Adam Awesome, that will definitely come in handy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's casting `tmp` as pointer to a function that accepts no arguments and returns nothing, then calling it.

Looks like a recipe for disaster, if you ask me.

Comment: In C there may well be a good use-case. For example, there may be a queue based generic inter-thread communication mechanism where everything is passed as a char* we then need to cast before using the data.

Comment: Technically, it is undefined as the C standard does not allow you to cast between non-function pointer and function pointer types. But most compilers allow it on most architectures as an extension